# Install Windows XP in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dual boot Windows XP and Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5344/how-do-i-dual-boot-windows-xp-and-ubuntu)

I have Ubuntu 11.04 on my hard disk. Now I want to create a NTFS partition for Windows XP and install Windows XP to get dual operating systems. How should I go about doing this ? How to create the partition in Linux? I am new to Linux..Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to boot from a live CD, run `sudo gparted`, resize your Ubuntu partition for room for XP, then [optional] create a NTFS for XP.  [Edit: If you're a total n00b, here is a link to a gparted tutorial: http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html ] :)

Then you boot from the XP cd, select the partition [or if you didn't create one, tell it to use unallocated space].

Once that installs, you are going to have to reinstall the GRUB bootloader.  If you have grub legacy, I know how. If you have grub-pc [the new one, aka grub 2 I think], I'm not exactly sure how, but a quick google search should tell you.

To reinstall the bootloader you again will have to boot from a live CD and run some commands on the terminal.

For legacy grub:  `sudo install-grub /dev/sdX`

And you may want to run `sudo update-grub`, [But you probably should backup `/boot/grub/menu.cfg` first] and hopefully it will find your XP installation and add it to the menu.  If not you will have to manually edit /boot/grub/menu.cfg.  `sudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.cfg`

If GRUB finds your windows XP automatically, you're done.

Find the part where it mentions chainloading, [it's commented out] and copy that part, and paste it next to your Linux entries.  Then just replace the "root (hd0,0)" line:  hd0 means the first disk [sda], the next 0 means the first partition. So if your XP partition was /dev/sda4, your line would look like "root (hd0,3)" because the number starts at 0, not 1.