# My PC has both Windows XP and Windows 8 installed. If I use Wubi to install Ubuntu, where should I  run the Wubi installer? XP or Win8?

Tags: boot, wubi, windows-xp, windows-8

I have decided to give Ubuntu a try using Wubi, but I don't know how this will work on my dual-booted PC.

I currently have Windows XP and Windows 8 consumer preview installed.

I went to the Ubuntu site and I saw that you can install Ubuntu inside Windows using Wubi, the Ubuntu Windows Installer. My question is where should I run the Wubi installer? In Windows XP or in Windows 8?

I am using the Windows 8 bootloader. Will Ubuntu show up in it? Will this actually work?

I am new to Ubuntu but I really want to give it a try.

Please help! Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Which **Ubuntu** version are you trying/intending to install?

Comment: On whichever one whose boot.ini gets used

Comment: Install it under XP. You said your Win 8 is Consumer Preview,so therefore I assume it contains some bugs, or you might consider upgrading it on Next Release. So it could be better if you Install it Under XP.

Comment: Yes it will work.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5344/how-do-i-dual-boot-windows-xp-and-ubuntu

Comment: That link above (from Curious Apprentice) show how to install grub. That's for a normal dual boot. Do NOT do this on a Wubi install - it will prevent both Windows and Grub from booting.

Answer (score 1):

Wubi installs Ubuntu inside Windows, so theoretically you should be able to install it either in XP or Windows 8. However, I would play it safe and try installing it in Windows 8 first since you're using that bootloader.